# Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles, one activity multiple fragment architecture

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm using one activity multiple fragments architecture with bottom navigation.
On pressing the same button in bottomNav i encounter with this error.

My viewModel code in fragement:

```
DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(DashboardViewModel.class);

dashboardViewModel.getLatLong().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),item ->{
    Log.i("uni","location expense "+item);
});
```

and the error in logcat as follows :

```
2022-01-14 14:13:35.388 5033-5824/smartsense.co.in.sensephone E/OneSignal: Error updating the user record because of the null user id
2022-01-14 14:15:21.045 5033-5033/smartsense.co.in.sensephone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: smartsense.co.in.sensephone, PID: 5033
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:199)
        at smartsense.co.in.sensephone.ui3.ExpenseFragment.onCreateView(ExpenseFragment.java:126)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```